# Merge candidates [vault] and [sourcegear-vault]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

While editing a question tagged with only [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, I thought that there might be a special tag called [vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault), which would better fit [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081638/lotusnotes-api-support-for-directly-uploading-the-id-file-to-vault-without-savi)

While performing the required edit, I came across this scenario :-

[image: Image containing tag]

As you can see from the image, there are two tags with similar description, and that too with almost similar name!

Tags are :-

[vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vault) ( 19 questions ) and [sourcegear-vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegear-vault) ( 54 questions )

Both have the same tag wiki

> Vault is a commercial, proprietary revision control system by SourceGear LLC which markets its product as a replacement for Microsoft's Visual Source Safe.

With my limited knowledge of using Stack Overflow, **I'd suggest that one of them(sourcegear-vault probably) should be made a synonym for the other one(vault probably)**.

Maybe you jury like the idea...

Comment: Tag formatting, since you metion it: [tag: tagname], minus the space